# What is the job title of the person who tries to get people to come inside a restaurant?

Tags: single-word-requests

Most of us have seen this: a person standing outside a restaurant, sometimes holding a menu, trying to entice passersby (usually tourists) to come in to dine.

Is it a "host/hostess"? Is it a "hawker"? What's the correct title for this person's job?

Comment: Reminds me of the days before Giuliani, on 42nd street and Times Square....except it wasn't to dine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Barker***

> a person who advertises an activity at a public event by calling out to people who are walking past:

-[Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/barker)

> a person who advertises by hawking at an entrance to a show

[-Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barker)

> a person who stands before a theater, carnival sideshow, or the like, calling out its attractions to passers-by

-[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/barker)

The usage is quite old, dating back to the 17th century. From [Etymology online...](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=barker)

> barker (n.)
>   late 14c., "a dog;" late 15c., "noisy fellow;" agent noun from bark (v.). Specific sense of "***loud assistant in an auction, store, or show"*** is from 1690s.
>    [Empahsis mine]

Comment: This is a nice suggestion, but I don’t think it   really fits what the OP is looking for. Probably because in the UK or in the USA these people who stand around the entrance of a restaurant and try to attract tourists  , showing them  the menu, for instance, is not so common. They can be found in southern  Europe for instance. In Italy they are called “buttadentro” (literary throw-in).

Comment: See images: https://www.google.it/search?q=buttadentro&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&prmd=mivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbwq-FzNLcAhULzqQKHTgkB8cQ_AUIEigC&biw=418&bih=546#imgdii=lHhVv8rMD7oFsM:&imgrc=2prGvpU8XOLU-M: